# Lost indian passport with Austrian schengen visa, How to continue travelling?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, austria

I lost my Indian passport with a three-month Schengen visa (Austrian) while travelling in France.

I have a new passport, but does anyone know the way in which I can continue to legally travel in the Schengen area? ( I have a passport, a copy of my visa and the police report along with my “Meldezettel”)